# JavaScript is not calling the next function as expected

Tags: javascript

This has got me stymied ... I am calling an external url (actually there are 2 calls one for the id of the data the next call is for the detail information what I want to capture is the lat & long from the second call) to place markers on a map

Here is the code it is being called from an `onload` event in the `body` element of my page

```
var firstpass = true;

function getResults(zip) {
        var zipi = parseInt(zip);
        // or
        // function getResults(lat, lng) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            // submit a get request to the restful service zipSearch or locSearch.
            url: "http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/zipSearch?zip=" + zipi,
            // or
            // url: "http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/locSearch?lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lng,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'searchResultsHandler'
        });
    }
    //iterate through the JSON result object.

function searchResultsHandler(searchResults) {
    for (var key in searchResults) {
        var results = searchResults[key];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var result = results[i];
            for (var key in result) {
                getDetails(result['id']);
            }
        }
    }
}

function getDetails(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        // submit a get request to the restful service mktDetail.
        url: "http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/mktDetail?id=" + id,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'detailResultHandler'
    });)

//iterate through the JSON result object.
function detailResultHandler(detailresults) {
    for (var key in detailresults) {
        alert(key);
        var results = detailresults[key];
        alert(results['GoogleLink']);
        var urlglink = (results["GoogleLink"]);
        var loca = (urlglink.split("q=")[1]);

        var lat = (loca.split("%2C%20")[0]);
        var long = (loca.split("%2C%20")[1]);
        var loc = (long.split("%20")[0]);
        var latlong = lat + "," + loc;

        var marker;
        if (firstpass === true) {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(latlong),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            firstpass = false;
        }


        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(latlong),
            map: map
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Which function isn't getting called? What is your console output?

Comment: detailResultHandler and I assumed it would be called by the line jsonpCallback: 'detailResultHandler'

Comment: update the original question please.

Comment: please see the answer shown below this actually fixed my issue with the calls thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), it shows setting `jsonp: false`:

> Override the callback function name in a jsonp request. This value
>   will be used instead of 'callback' in the 'callback=?' part of the
>   query string in the url. So {jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'} would result in
>   'onJSONPLoad=?' passed to the server. As of jQuery 1.5, setting the
>   jsonp option to false prevents jQuery from adding the "?callback"
>   string to the URL or attempting to use "=?" for transformation. In
>   this case, you should also explicitly set the jsonpCallback setting.
>   For example, { jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }

The example at the bottom, and the part that says:

> ...setting the
>   jsonp option to false prevents jQuery from adding the "?callback"
>   string to the URL or attempting to use "=?" for transformation"...

Comment: That was it appreciate your help need to brush up on jQuery a little more.